# Resolve Linq.Expressions.NewExpression?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

How can I 'compile' the [`NewExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.newexpression) to instantiate the pointed `new` expression?

Do I have to construct the object manually or I can just get the constructed object as an argument?

Gonna update my question with an example soon.

```
class Obj
{
  public async Task ParseAsync<TObj>(Expression<Func<TObj, Task>> pointedMethod)
  {
    var method = pointedMethod.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    var arg = method.Arguments[0];
    var newExp = arg as NewExpression;

    //This is what I need:
    User = newExp.ConstructObject();
    await Task.FromResult((object)null);
  }

  public async Task MyMethod(User user)
  {
    await Task.FromResult((object)null);
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var obj = new Obj();

  obj.ParseAsync<Obj>(o => o.MyMethod(new User())).Wait();
}
```

Notes:
At execution time, there won't be a proper reference to `TObj`, the item has to be constructed solely from the arguments provided to the `ParseAsync` function.
Since I have a `NewExpression` it means that the object (`User` in my example) is capable of being constructed.
The question is if there is a way of instantiating the object without walking manually finding the constructor and calling it etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was originally answered by @[dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight), I have no clue why he deleted it, it just worked. Anyway should he choose to undelete his answer and I'll delete mine and credit him!

Anyway for the reference:

> The answer depends on whether or not the NewExpression in question
>   references any parameters, and if you have access to these parameter
>   expressions in case it does.
>
> If NewExpression has no parameters, simply construct a lambda
>   expression from it, compile, and run:
>
> ```
> NewExpression myNewExpression = ... // You have this
> var instantiator = (Func<MyResultType>)Expression
>     .Lambda<Func<MyResultType>>(myNewExpression)
>     .Compile();
> MyResultType res = instantiator();
> ```